# On the interval $(0,1)$ $9$ points are chosen at random.Let $X$ be the distance from $0$ to the medium between the chosen points.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

On the interval $(0,1)$ 9 points are chosen at random.- This most likely means uniformly, I doesn't say more than was is written, just the presumption of choosing these points is what comes to mind naturally reading it.

Let $X$ be the distance from $0$ to the medium between the chosen points(meaning the distance from $0$). Find the density function of $X$ and the expected value as well... To be honest I haven't made any tangible progress toward the answer..

Comment: Do you mean "median" or "mean"? "Medium" is not, as far as I know, a commonly-used English statistical term.

Comment: By medium I mean the value of the distance between 0 and the chosen point which is ranked fifth in distance from $0$. Now this applies to one of your "median" or "mean" I don't know which one yet. But I am interested in the answer if the word had the other meaning aswell, curiosity wise..

Comment: That is the "median" in common English. And since any $x\in (0,1)$ the distance between $x$ and $0$ is just $x$, so the language "distance from $0$" is redundant.

Comment: The expected value is easy - $\frac{1}{2}$. This is because the set has some symmetric properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean *median*, not medium. Think of it this way, what're the odds that the median is $\leq M$ for some $M$? We'd have to pick *at least* 5 points below $M$ and the rest above $M$, for any choice of points. That is:
$$
\begin{split}
Pr(X \leq M) &= \binom{9}{5}M^5(1-M)^4 \\
&+ \binom{9}{6}M^6(1-M)^3 \\
&+ \binom{9}{7}M^7(1-M)^2 \\
&+ \binom{9}{8}M^8(1-M)^1 \\
&+  M^9
\end{split}$$

As a sanity check, $Pr(X \leq 1) = 1$, since the first four terms are $0$. To get the pdf, we just differentiate the above, coming up with:

$$PDF = 630M^4(1-M)^4$$

And then to find the expected value:

$$\begin{split}
E[X] &= \int_0^1630M^5(1-M)^4dM \\
&= \left.630(\frac{M^{10}}{10}-\frac{4M^9}{9}+\frac{3M^8}{4}-\frac{4M^7}{7}+\frac{M^6}{6})\right|_0^1 \\
&= \frac12
\end{split}$$

Comment: Could you explain the other terms here ? from $
...=....  \binom{9}{6}M^6(1-M)^3 
+ \binom{9}{7}M^7(1-M)^2 
+ \binom{9}{8}M^8(1-M)^1 
+  M^9 $

Comment: @BozoVulicevic If exactly 5 points are below $M$, $X$ will be. But that's true if 6 points are below $M$ also... or 7... or 8... or all 9.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, upvote my question, if you already haven't.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Could this be done using variational series ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $W$ be the distance from $0$ to the fifth largest point. We want to find $F_W(w)$, the probability that $W \le w$. This is the probability that at least $5$ of our numbers are $\le w$. The density can then be obtained by differentiating.

The probability exactly $5$ are $\le w$ is $\binom{9}{5}w^5(1-w)^4$.

The probability exactly $6$ are $\le w$ is $\binom{9}{6}w^6 (1-w)^3$.

And so on.

**Remarks:** $1.$ We do not need the density function in order to find the mean of $W$: it is $\frac{1}{2}$ by symmetry.

$2.$ The expression for $F_W(w)$ in the answer above is somewhat messy, and then we need to differentiate. Here is an alternate way to obtain the density directly. The idea is useful for calculating the density of the order statistics for a sample of $n$ from a continuous distribution.

We argue informally. The median lies between $w$ and $w+dw$ with probability about $f_W(w)\,dw$. We compute this probability another way. We want $1$ observation to be between $w$ and $w+dw$, and $4$ of the observations to lie below, and $4$ to lie above. The probability of $2$ or more observations in the interval is negligible, so our probability is approximately $\left(\binom{9}{1}dw\right)\binom{8}{4}w^4(1-w)^4)$. That yields $f_W(w)=\binom{9}{1}\binom{8}{4}w^4(1-w)^4$.

Answer (score 2):

For the pdf, you have four numbers less than $x$ and four numbers greater than $x$, so the pdf is proportional to $x^4(1-x)^4$.  All you have to do is normalize it, so the integral from $0$ to $1$ is $1$.

Comment: Well, the integral is $1/630$, so this method agrees with Barry's.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? Why the pdf is proportional to $x^4(1-x)^4$?